# TreeView with RadioButtons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I need to create TreeView with dynamicly node creation in my WPF project. There is one condition for TreeView Nodes. All leafs must contains Radiobuttons with work logic same as group of RadioButtons.

I have this XAML code, that describes treeview data template:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="sko_ver_hdt">
        <RadioButton Margin="0,0,10,0" Content="{Binding Version}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="sko_hdt"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource sko_ver_hdt}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I've tried to use CollectionViewSource to group nodes of TreeView like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding SKOs}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Version"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

but nothing happens.

I have a model that describes treeview data:

```
internal class SKOVM
{
    public SKOVM(DBCommunication.SKO sko)
    {
        Name = sko.Name;
        Version = sko.VersionCode;
        Id = sko.Id;
        Children = new ObservableCollection<SKOVM>(sko.SKO1.Select(x => new SKOVM(x)));
        sko.SKOSystemInformationReference.Load();
        if (sko.SKOSystemInformation != null)
            Version = String.Format("{0} / {1}", Version, sko.SKOSystemInformation.Designer);
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<SKOVM> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas how i can implement grouped radiobuttons behaviour logic to my treeview leaf nodes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped you to solve your problem, so that this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the [`RadioButton.GroupName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="sko_ver_hdt">
    <RadioButton Content="{Binding Version}" GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

This property *Gets or sets the name that specifies which RadioButton controls are mutually exclusive*. So you'll need a property in the child item class where the child items of each group will have the same value. In this way, you can data bind that value to the `GroupName` property and the `RadioButton` of each child item should work in their individual groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You realy help me. Everything works just as I planed.